# Anova for multiple point patterns not working for Strauss model

Tags: statistics, spatial, anova, spatstat

I just started getting into spatial analysis and am fitting some models to my data. My main goal is to test for spatial regularity (whether there is inhibition between points).

I created my hyperframe  for the data below. There are 6 point patterns (Areas), 4 in subhabitat 1, and 2 in subhabitat 2.

```
ALL_ppp <- list(a1ppp, a2ppp, a3ppp, a4ppp, a5ppp, a6ppp) 
H <- hyperframe(Area = c("A1","A2","A3","A4","A5","A6"), Subhabitat = c("sbh1","sbh1","sbh1","sbh1","sbh2","sbh2"), Points = ALL_ppp )
```

I then created some models. This model fits a Strauss process with a different interaction radius for each area, with intensity depending on subhabitat type. It is very similar to the example in the book on page 700.

```
radii <- c(mean(area1$diameter), mean(area2$diameter),mean(area3$diameter),mean(area4$diameter),mean(area5$diameter),mean(area6$diameter))
Rad <- hyperframe(R=radii)
Str <- with(Rad, Strauss(R))
Int <- hyperframe(str=Str)

fittest8 <- mppm(Points ~ Subhabitat, H, interaction=Int, iformula = ~str:Area)
```

I would like to conduct a formal test for significance for the Strauss interaction parameters using anova.mppm to test for regularity. However, I am not sure if I am doing this properly, as I cannot seem to get this to work. I have tried:

```
fittest8 <- mppm(Points ~ Subhabitat, H, interaction=Int, iformula = ~str:Area)
fitex <- mppm(Points ~ Subhabitat, H)
anova.mppm(fittest8, fitex, test = "Chi")
```

I get the error "Error: Coefficient ‘str’ is missing from new.coef" and cannot find a way to resolve this. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, please learn how to make a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This will make it easier for people to help you solve the problem, without having to guess what was in your data.

In your example, the columns named `Area` and `Subhabitat` in the hyperframe `H` are character vectors, but in your code, the call to `mppm` would require that they are factors. I assume you converted them to factors in order to be able to fit the model `fittest8`. (Another reason to make a working example)

You said that your example was similar to one on page 700 of [the spatstat book](https://book.spatstat.org) which does work. In that case, a good strategy is to modify your example to make it as similar as possible to the example that works, because this will narrow down the possible cause.

A working example of the problem, similar to the one in the book, is:

```
Str <- hyperframe(str=with(simba, Strauss(mean(nndist(Points)))))
fit1 <- mppm(Points ~ group, simba, interaction=Str, iformula=~str:group)
fit0 <- mppm(Points ~ group, simba)
anova(fit0, fit1, test="Chi")
```

which yields the same error `Error: Coefficient ‘str’ is missing from new.coef`

The simplest way to avoid this is to replace the interaction formula `~str:group` by `str+str:group`:

```
fit1x <- mppm(Points ~ group, simba, interaction=Str, 
           iformula = ~str + str:group)
anova(fit0, fit1x, test="Chi")
```

or in your example

```
fittest8X <- mppm(Points ~ Subhabitat, H, interaction=Int, 
           iformula=~str + str:Area)
anova(fittest8X, fitex, test="Chi")
```

Note that `fittest8X` and `fittest8` are equivalent models but are expressed in a slightly different way.

The interaction formula and the trend formula are connected in a complicated way and the software is not always successful in disentangling them. If you get this kind of problem again, try different versions of the interaction formula.

Comment: Hi, thank you for responding. The model format you suggested did indeed work, but just two quick clarifications: While I do get the anova output, I also get an error saying "Internal error: Unable to map submodel to full model." Additionally, regarding interpretation, while the p-value is highly significant for the anova, the canonical Strauss interaction parameters for Areas 2-4 in the model output summary are not. I am interpreting this as "there is evidence of significant spatial inhibition/regularity, but only in areas 1, 5 and 6." Would this be correct? Thank you.

Comment: Some code was broken. It is now fixed in the development version of `spatstat.core` (version 2.3-2.006`).